# How use ng-view inside ng-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I have main ng-view, and controller with left\right side. The right side is fixed, but left side I want change by other templates and controllers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MTxmmZWRY7O0nH88qK3F

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  Choose:
  <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
  <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

  <div class="left-side view-animate-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="some-fixed-right-side">

  <pre>$location.path() = {{main.$location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{main.$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.params = {{main.$route.current.params}}</pre>
  <pre>$routeParams = {{main.$routeParams}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It means u want to open a page in left panel on click or what?

Comment: You should use ui route instead of ng-route to get multiple views as well as other features.. like slug, states etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a solution derived from here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm

Allowing me to effectively nest views (and skipping the limited ng-view altogether)

After doing so, this other (simpler, better, I believe) solution appeared:

http://angular-ui.github.com/ (scroll down to "Route Checking")

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Just use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router for that. It allows using nested views.